# Error duiring configuring cicd to github for jenkins pipeline in minishift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-online, openshift-web-console

I have installed openshift in my Mac OS sierra 10. I have started it using minishift start. I am able to successfully create a node application and configured a jenkins  tool chain for it. when I tried to run the pipeline  manually it worked. But then I wanted to use CICD with github. So  I have used `oc describe bc mynode` which gave me the webhook. I have replaced the secret id with the ID in my pipeline YAML file. after configuring the webhook in the github and diasbling ssl. I clicked redeliver. then I got this error We couldn't deliver  this payload, couldn't connect to server. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub needs to be able to contact your minishift instance. Normally you minishift instance would not be on the public Internet, so GitHub cannot do that.